# How do I include my `css` and 'js' files, whose paths are defined in` index.html` in my React project, into bundle?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, bundle, assets

good work everyone.
I have React project that I created with webpack. I want to include my `css` and `js` files in `index.html` in the bundle process. But the `css` and `js` files in the `index.html` file extracted to the `dist` folder fail in the paths. When I view the page source and click on the links, I get an error like this:

> Cannot GET /dist/js/adminlte.js

I had no such problems in the project I created with `create-react-app`. It reads `css` and `js` files directly in "index.html".

I have to mention it from the beginning, I encountered errors that I defined my javascript files in `index.tsx`.

> There is no problem in `css` files defined in `index.tsx` file. There is a problem with the `css` and `js` files defined only in `index.html`.

How do I include my `css` and 'js' files, whose paths are defined in `index.html` in my React project, into bundle?